# New iCalendar "Event announcement" in C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, icalendar

I'm trying to add a new event to the Lotus Notes calendar sending a mail with c#.
Everything is working fine, but I want to set "Event announcement" type instead of "Meeting".

Here's my .ics so far

```
 StringBuilder bodyCalendar = new StringBuilder();
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("PRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:{8}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("DTSTART:{0}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("SUMMARY:{7}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("UID:{5}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{9}\":MAILTO:{9}");
            foreach (MailAddress attendee in attendeeList)
            {
                bodyCalendar.AppendLine("ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"" + attendee + "\":MAILTO:" + attendee);
            }
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{4}\":MAILTO:{4}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("ORGANIZER;CN=\"{3}\":mailto:{4}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("LOCATION:{2}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("DTEND:{1}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:{7}\\N");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:1");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("PRIORITY:5");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("CLASS:");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("CREATED:{8}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("LAST-MODIFIED:{8}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-1");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ATTENDEE-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNER-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:REMINDER");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            bodyCalendar.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
```

I tried to use both 0 and 1 values in the line

```
bodyCalendar.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0");
```

but nothing changed. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "event announcement" but if people are not supposed to accept/decline the invitation, you want to use a `METHOD:PUBLISH` instead of `METHOD:REQUEST`. This implicitly means that you should also remove the `ATTENDEE` property. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.1

Comment: I found out that (in Lotus Notes) "event announcement" is like a meeting but do not receive responses from invitees. This is what I am interested in, how to avoid the organizer to receive a mail back when someone accept/decline the meeting.
The problem is solved using METHOD:PUBLISH, thanks!

Comment: I have a new problem now. Everything is working fine, I receive the mail and it creates the event in my calendar, but then I cannot remove/decline this new event using Lotus Notes! Heeeelp!!

Comment: Hmm, can't help you with Lotus Notes specific questions, sorry.